# Strange text on shirt

Tags: phrases, slang

Is this text correct?

> Dont ever let anyone tell you you aine beautiful

Someone told me that this is correct:

> it's a phonetic transcription (Afro Americans discard a lot of phonetic rules while speaking)

[image]

Comment: So. You've got your answer already. (Its wording is complete BS, and racist BS to boot, but it's the answer alright.) What else is it that you need?

Comment: I want to confirm this answer, thanks :) Btw, what mean BS?

Comment: @RegDwigнt Well my answer below might be helpful ;)

Comment: Regardless of what is written, that is one ugly-looking t-shirt. Everything about it screams "cheap" and "nasty" and "fake". If this were really written in true [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)  why is the the spelling of *beautiful* 100% correct?

Comment: What means 'BS'?

Comment: @RegDwigнt ?? How is it racist? (and what is 'it' you're referring to? The t-shirt wording is pretty everyday to me).

Comment: @MariuszS BS = Bull Shit = not necessarily true or false but just words to sound true.

Comment: Is the issue 'Why 'aine' instead of 'aint'?" Isn't that obviously a typo?

Comment: yes, this is about 'aine'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no speakers of any particular variety of a language who disregard phonetic rules, although individual speakers of any language may have medical conditions such as hearing loss or a speech impediment which may prevent them from speaking conventionally.

Different varieties of a language may have *different* phonetic and phonological rules but they all have rules, they are all extremely complex and sophisticated and difficult to analyse.

However, in this particular case the feature concerned, which is alveolar plosive elision, specifically the elision of /t/ in negative contractions, is a feature of almost *all* varieties of English. It is certainly an expected feature of both General American and Southern Standard British English.

Negative contractions such as *can't*, *won't*, *musn't* and so forth are most likely to be pronounced with a glottal stop at the end of the word, /ʔ/. The word *isn't*, for example, will usually be pronounced [ɪznʔ]. The *second* most likely realisation for negative contractions will be with a complete elision of the /t/. So, for example, we might expect to see /kæn/, [kæn,] for the word *can't* in Gen Am. The least likely realisation for negative contractions in English is with a canonical /t/ in the form of an alveolar plosive. In other words, the least likely thing we should expect is [ɪznt].

[I have kept this simple and ignored the fact that [t] may be replaced by a voiced allophone in this position, albeit still an alveolar one]

In varieties of English which use the word *ain't* as a negative contraction, we should, if we expect them to have the similar phonological rules for negative contractions, expect the following realisations to be the most frequent:

- eɪnʔ
- eɪn

Only someone who expected a group of speakers to behave abnormally should expect this as the most frequent realisation of *ain't*:

- eɪnt

This expectation would say more about the person's unfamiliarity with the actual language that they themselves speak than anything else.

If you want a sociological analysis of the t-shirt, see RegDwight's comment under the question.

Comment: The odd thing is that this same feature isn’ reflected in the word _don’t_ further up. Though I guess a similar approach, yielding _done_, would be a bit confusing…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I dunno about that ;)

Comment: For one upvote, what would be the AAVE for *beautiful*? How would it be pronounced?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not one of my areas of middling expertise I'm afraid ... :( Can *you* tell *me*?

Comment: Oh, I was hoping you would. I'd be tempted to say [*bootiful*](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2010/apr/16/advertising-bernard-matthews-bootiful) but hasn't that be claimed by Norfolk? :) *Booty* is AmEng for *bum*, so there must be an equivalent for *beautiful*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I'd recognise that as Norfolk too! I don't know about AAVE though! Might well be ...

Comment: Interesting grammar-school-approved use of _anyone_ in place of _no one_, too.